# Flutter: change background for 1s

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, background-color

I found loads of questions around changing the background every few seconds or after a few seconds. Not sure if it is too late in the evening or if my case works differently. I want to change the background color of a container for 1s in case of a certain event.

```dart
setState(() {
  flashBackground = (answer == result ? false : true);
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {flashBackground = false;});
});
```

This triggers the background of the container

`color: (flashBackground ? CupertinoColors.destructiveRed : CupertinoColors.white)`

When flashBackground is set to true, the background turns destructiveRed (I love it), but the timer does not return the color to white, afterwards. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TweenAnimationBuilder-class.html) is more suitable for your requirement.

Comment: You are using setState to change the color, but when the timer runs out, you are not setting the state again, thus your app is not updating the state to reflect the new color. Use the link provided by Hiwa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  bool _changeColor = false;

  void _changeBackgroundColor() {
    setState(() => _changeColor = !_changeColor);
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1),
        () => setState(() => _changeColor = !_changeColor));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _changeBackgroundColor,
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: _changeColor ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```